# RDotNet evaluate with json or dataTable columns

Tags: c#, json, r, r.net

I am using RDOTNET and not very clear on how to convert the data (json) to vectors.

```
public string Calculate(string input, string formula)
        {
            if (_rEngine == null)
                CreateEngine();

        dynamic list;
        if (input != null)
        {
            list = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(input);
            NumericVector vSpread = new NumericVector(_rEngine, ((DynamicJsonArray) list).Length);
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                //TODO...
            }
        }
```

}

Is there any preferred way of converting input data to vectors? For start, the formula here is simple like (columna * columnb)

Answer (score 0):

This error can be rectified by using setsymbol as follows:

```
engine.SetSymbol("vSpread", vSpread);
```

I think using the following sample would help you create a vector:

```
engine.Evaluate("exec").AsIntegerMatrix();
```

For more doubts, please check the following link:
   http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_basic_types/